# Re-write the content of DIV container instead of creating new HTML file

Tags: html, html-lists

I am newbie and I need to create a navigation menu for my web-site. A standard way to create it would be the following:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="default.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html>Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, each time the navigation item is selected, a new HTML file is opened. But is it possible to re-write the content of particular DIV container instead of creating new HTML file?

Comment: Not with just plain HTML. You'll need to add in some other type of technology to enable your reuse of this snippet.

Comment: @Klausos see my updated answer with fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery.  See http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2 for details on changing the HTML contents of an element and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ for details on fetching content asynchronously using AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

This fiddle might assist you: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/JgReZ/

Also read: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs

@Shawn's technique is the basis of how any solution to your problem will work more or less. But as you suggest being a newbie, I would suggest you look at this linked tutorial. Although it doesn't answer you question directly, it is exactly the technology you want to use. The technique is called Single Page Applications

http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will allow re-writing containers' content.  jQuery has tools to make this easier as posted above; learn here: http://tutsplus.com/lesson/creating-and-appending-content/

IMHO I would not "re-write" menus ever, but I would use CSS & extra tags to point out what page you are on.  If you keep radically changing the menu, the you will lose or frustrate visitors.

Comment: I don't want to re-write menu. What I want is to change the content of particular DIV block once HOME, CONTACT or any other menu option is selected.